# потокобезопастность. segmentation fault

Tags: c++, многопоточность, segmentation-fault

У меня есть `std::deque<int> q`.
Задача следующая: мне надо наполнить эту очередь с разных потоков.
Если я делаю так `q.push_back(i)`, то получаю Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Если же перед добавлением елемента заблокировать очередь мютексом:

```
std::unique_lock lock(mux); 
q.push_back(i)
```

то так работает.
Почитал что Segmentation fault говорит о том что идёт запись в память в которую нет доступа.
Где тут не разрешенная память?

Comment: блокировки это конечно не очень хорошо - я про мютексы. я бы взял спинлок или бы подумал о lock-free queue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Упрощенно метод `push_back` реализован так (детали могут отличаться, но суть - та же и на конечный результат это не влияет):

```
void push_back (const value_type& val) {
   if (insert_idx == storage_length) {             // 1
      storage_length *= 2                          // 2
      old_storage = storage                        // 3
      storage = allocate_memory(storage_length);   // 4
      copy(old_storage, storage);                  // 5
      deallocate_memory(old_storage);              // 6
   }
   storage[insert_idx++] = val;                    // 7
}
```

Теперь если этот метод выполянется паралельно из двух потоков, то возможен например такой порядок выполнения:

```
   поток 1   |   поток 2    |
-------------+--------------+-
     1       |              |
     2       |      1       |
             |      7       |
```

Обратите внимание, что при этом поток 2 записывает за границу массива `storage`. Вот вам и Segmentation fault.

Детали, конечно, могут отличаться, но суть та же - сама по себе реализация контейнера не является потокобезопасной, а потому в результате - undefined behavior. Причина в том, что изменения во внутренней структуре неатомарны и при обращении из разных потоков, один видит состояние в процессе изменения, когда, например, информация о выделенном размере уже изменилась, а сам массив еще старый.

Даже если допустить, что реализация делает изменение хранилища атомарно, возникает проблема с публикацией изменений. Т.е. один поток меняет хранилище на новое и освобождает память, которую занимал старый массив. Но это изменение не видно в другом потоке, так как реализация не пробует даже опубликовать изменения. И другой поток, продолжает себе записывать данные по старому указателю, который уже нействителен.

Вот всего лишь два примера, как может случиться, то что вы наблюдаете. Что происходит на самом деле, зависит от реализации, и сказать однозначно нельзя.